# Как сделать вывод acf Repeater - в обратном порядке?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть блок с выводом acf Repeater - как сделать чтоб последние выводились первыми?
Делать через стили не вариант ( display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; )
В блоке есть scroll - и получается что он отображает первый в низу и нужно прокручивать вверх.

Comment: Делаете `get_field()` Вашего репитера и сохраняете в переменную, затем `array_reverse()` и можете перебрать в `foreach()`, либо можно без `array_reverse()` но с использованием счетчика, только не увеличивать его, а  уменьшать `$i--`, чтобы делать перебор в обратном порядке.